# Access denied creating initial database- how do I grant the right access?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a new project on heroku, using mysql (they have an addon called JawsDB, which gives me a mysql host, username, password).  (Update: I've also tried using their other mysql addon, ClearDB, and I have the exact same issue)

I can connect to the database like so (and I can 'show databases' to see what's there):

```
mysql -h izm96dhhnwr2ieg0.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u knu81lzn5m79u3rx -p[given_password]
```

**Problem**: When I do create database `nptest`, I get:

```
Access denied for user 'knu81lzn5m79u3rx'@%' to database 'nptest'
```

I've tried granting all privileges, like this:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'knu81lzn5m79u3rx'@'%' identified by '[given_password]';
```

but that gives me:

```
Access denied for user 'knu81lzn5m79u3rx'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I also tried create user to make a fresh one, but of course then it's "Access denied" because I don't have create user privileges either.

What's the correct way to grant access to this user?

Comment: Update: I have the exact same issue when I try with heroku's other mysql add-on (cleardb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further clarify on Diane's answer, the cryptic database name can be found by logging into JawsDB via a mysql client and running`show databases` or it's the last parameter of the JAWSDB_URL that can be found running `heroku config`.

Answer (score 5):

Ah!  The answer was that the preliminary plan on jawsDB gives you one specific database (that has a cryptic name) on a shared server with other people, so you don't have permissions to make a new one.  It wasn't clear in the instructions, so now I'm humming away with good old database "tbkrv66g085ulngi" :)

Comment: I got the exact same results you got above.  But what do I need to do.

Comment: So in this case instead of trying to create a new one, I made use of the free one they gave me with a cryptic name. (Or it sounds like the other solution is to upgrade to the type of plan where you can create an additional database).

Answer (score 0):

i think if you use it in production mode it will solve the probl