# Jawsdb on heroku, new database post migration, (Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user..?)

Tags: mysql, heroku

Deployed a new version of our app on heroku and migrated over database from previous free jawsdb instance. However now every time user signs up gives

`(Mysql2::Error: INSERT command denied to user <username for instance`

what have i missed

- migrated using a dump and re-import using mysql command line. eye balled exported data and it seems to be there (user emails etc)
- all config vars look ok (DATABASE_URL is `mysql2...`)
- i can login to the database via the url

I have not had to grant access or anything like that before, anyone come across this?

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 9):

My guess is they disabled your `INSERT` grant because you have reached your max Storage Capacity for your plan.

To validate this is a permissions problem, log into a MySQL prompt with the user the app is running as, and enter this query:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

It probably list many, but no `INSERT`.

Comment: it's very intriguing as when you create the addon the database permissions are completely different and it took me a while as I thought the migration script was actually changing the permissions. Only then I've noticed that the free tier has a pretty tiny limit of only 5MB. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228389/access-denied-creating-initial-database-how-do-i-grant-the-right-access). As explained in given link, jawsdb preliminary plan does not give you permission to add a new database. You are provided with one schema with some random name and you have to work with that only.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your migration**

e.g. Make sure the database name matches.

For me, I got the same error as OP when trying to migrate my data. This was a fresh account with only a 50kb'ish database; nowhere close to the free-plan 5mb limit.

In my SQL export statement, my local database name is being used, however the remote MySQL (ie JawsDB) service auto-generates a db name, which will obviously not be the same. Simply used find-replace to change the database name to match remote; everything works.