# Unable To Migrate .SQL File to JawsDb (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Using the following command

```
mysql -h erxv1bzckceve5lh.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u 
remoteUsername -premotePassword java-play-app < mazzo_play_app.sql
```

I am receiving the following error in the console:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mh45rmnau81wvfct'@'%' to database 'java-play-app'
```

What do I need to do exactly to make this connection?
Thanks,
CM

Answer (score 1):

[image]  I was frustrated by this as well....but I found the answer! note that you have to put the password on with NO space between it and the -p link. Once I did that, it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant access to that user to the schemas involved. If you have root access you can do it.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
```

In this case it seems you can't have direct root access to MySQL.
The official guide (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb) reports:

1) Dump the data from the original DB:

```
mysqldump -h OLDHOST -u OLDUSER -pOLDPASS OLDDATABASE > backup.sql
```

2) Put the data in the new DB:

```
mysql -h NEWHOST -u NEWUSER -pNEWPASS NEWDATABASE < backup.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I've tried something like this.  So let me get clarification.  In your syntax, does 'myuser'@'%' represent the 'root', the user that access the database I'm trying to export? Or does 'myuser' represent 'mh45rmnau81wvfct' which is the username of the remote db.  And does @'%' represent @'localhost'? or @'remotehost'?

Comment: 'myuser' would be the user to whom you want to grant access, in your example 'mh45rmnau81wvfct'. '%' is a wildcard which means that that user should be allowed to connect from any host. Check [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html) for details.

Comment: How do I do that on the remote server though?  I'm issuing that command from inside my SQL terminal on my local machine.

Comment: Do you have root access ? As Matt pointed you need to change 'mydb' to 'java-play-app' and 'myuser' to 'mh45rmnau81wvfct'. You connect to the database as root and you run the command.

Comment: I'm confused. I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think I have root access to the remote server.

Comment: who is providing you the database ? amazon ? Do they give you any external tool to setup the database, or ssh access to it ?

Comment: It's Heroku. I'm connecting a Java Play app to a JawsDB add-on.  I can log into my own local MySQL server as root no problem and grant privileges to users there. But how to do this to the remote JawsDB?

Comment: The JawsDb server is called "java-play-app"

Comment: I can use a GUI tool called HeidiSQL but when I try and import the .sql file I get the same access denial message.

Comment: Thank you for that farbiondriven.  I did see that documentation.  And my original post, uses that command syntax.  My original post begins with step 2.  I did the dump.  And then ran that command.  And got that error.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228389/access-denied-creating-initial-database-how-do-i-grant-the-right-access. They should have assigned you a specific schema where to put your dump.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156740/discussion-between-farbiondriven-and-chris-mazzochi).